# Not able to read user attribute from OU of a active directory in java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I have OU (say ou1) in AD server and it has a user (say user1).
I want query all the users belong to a OU of AD directory server.
I am trying as show below :

```
SearchControls ouctls = new SearchControls();
String[] ouattrIDs = {"displayname", "mail", "canonicalName", "memberOf","Users"};
ctls.setReturningAttributes(ouattrIDs);
ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

NamingEnumeration ouanswer = ctx.search("dc=exam,dc=com","(objectclass=group)", ouctls);
```

and  by these I am not find user attribute populated.

```
while (ouAnswer.hasMoreElements()) {
        SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult) ouAnswer.next();
        Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes();
        //log.debug("Group attributes"+attrs.get("cn"));
        System.out.println("gr-->"+attrs.toString());
        Attribute temp = attrs.get("cn");
}
```

Can you please help me in finding user object under a OU.

Answer (score 0):

If by this you mean that `user1` is subordinate to `ou=ou1` and you know the distinguished name of the `ou`, use that as the base object in the search request. For example, if the `ou` is immediately subordinate to `dc=exam,dc=com`, use `ou=ou1,dc=exam,dc=com` as the base object in the search. In this case, if you know that the user entries are immediately subordinate to `ou=ou1`, the search scope can be tightened to one level. Otherwise, subtree scope must be used. Use a filter that narrows the results that would be returned from the server. In the example you give, perhaps the filter should be: `(&(cn=user1)(objectclass=group))`. This assumes that the naming attribute of user1 is `cn` and the entry is a member of objectClass `group. Use the correct values in the code for the LDAP client.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)
- [LDAP: Search Best Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)